# How does Sitecore read .jssconfig and .sxaconfig files?

Tags: configuration

So we know that `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory` reads through all files ending in `*.config` in the `App_Config/Include` folder of your website root.

But I've seen with SXA and JSS, that additional config files are placed in these directories.

[image]

Are these picked up by as any other config files as well?  or does SXA and JSS respectively "hook into" Sitecore's configuration mechanics to read these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are not Sitecore patch config files, and as such they are not read by the Sitecore Configuration Factory, so nothing has changed in that regard with only `.config` files being loaded.

If you inspect the contents of the config files using Notepad, you'll notice they are all changes that should be applied to the `web.config` file. For example, in *Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.MediaRequestHandler.jssconfig*:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecorejss_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media" name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is not patching a `<sitecore>` section of the config, it's targeting an element in the root `web.config`. This is automatically applied by a post-install step when you install the JSS and SXA packages respectively:

- `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Install.PostInstall, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Install`
- `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Installer.ExperienceAcceleratorInstallationPostStep, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Installer`

In each of these post-install steps there is a method which checks for all `.jssconfig` and `.sxaconfig` files within the `/App_Config` folder and applies the required changes to the `web.config`. Once you have installed the packages, you should check the `web.config` to ensure that the relevant changes have been applied.

NOTE: If you have checked in the stock `web.config` into your source code, then you should ensure that these changes have also been applied. Unlike some earlier modules, the fact that these `web.config` changes are required is not mentioned in any of the documentation.